# Use list of values in procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, psql

I'm trying to create a stored procedure to update a row with a list of pre determined values for example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateNaturePassword(@_email AS VARCHAR(256))
AS
DECLARE 
    SET @hashedPasswordList = '["{bcrypt}$2a$10",{bcrypt}$2a$10$Kh8YS.","{bcrypt}$2a$10$safds","{bcrypt}$2a$10$Wl8ZKTF2YGobQ6yi"]'; 
    SET randomIndexValue = (look at the list size and gets a random index);
    SET hashedPassword = hashed_password_list[randomIndexValue];;
BEGIN
    UPDATE accounts 
    SET passwd = hashed_password 
    WHERE lower (email) =lower (@_email);
END;
```

The easier thing is to create a table, insert these random passwords and select them but I cannot create another table.

Any ideas? sorry if this is very simple but I'm just starting to work with databases.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Are you just trying to set your passwd column to a random value from your list? If that is the case you should put those values into a table and select top 1 order by newid(). Also, you have declared your parameter as varchar but did not specify the size. Do you know what the default length is? Do you know that the default length changes for variables and parameters? https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Comment: Will the list be fixed and defined in the procedure?  If it's a parameter, then that limits options.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm quite new at this.
This will be a fixed list of passwords, I just need to randomly select one and update the table.

Comment: The length of the email varchar should be speficied (e.g., (varchar(256))

Comment: Why the `psql` tag? Are you trying to write a procedure for SQL Server or PostgreSQL?

Comment: Just define a table variable in your procedure, populate that with your list of values and get one at random.

Comment: As the person in the desert mentioned, the tag in the password hash might not be needed.  I don't know how it's used, so I left it.  A salty password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the password string was an argument, then perhaps STRING_SPLIT.  Instead, I start with a local table.  This is not a procedure yet, but it can be adapted. Also, the use of lower fn in the where will prevent the the use of an index - research sargable if interested.  I removed the fn, but if your database is case sensitive, it would be time to really think about life and performance.

```
DECLARE @_email AS VARCHAR(128)

DECLARE @hashedPasswordList as table (
    ID int IDENTITY,
    HashedPassword varchar(128)
)

DECLARE @randomIndex int
DECLARE @hashedPassword varchar(128)

INSERT INTO @hashedPasswordList (HashedPassword) VALUES ('{bcrypt}$2a$10'),('{bcrypt}$2a$10$Kh8YS.'),('{bcrypt}$2a$10$safds'),('{bcrypt}$2a$10$Wl8ZKTF2YGobQ6yi')

SET @randomIndex = 1 + FLOOR( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @hashedPasswordList) * RAND() )
SELECT @hashedPassword = HashedPassword FROM @hashedPasswordList WHERE ID = @randomIndex

UPDATE accounts 
SET passwd = @hashedPassword
WHERE email = @_email
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of doing this is a procedure using order by newid. Pretty straight forward and simple.

```
create or alter procedure updateNaturePassword
(
    @_email AS VARCHAR(256)
) as

    set nocount on;
    
    DECLARE @hashedPasswordList as table 
    (
        HashedPassword varchar(128)
    )

    INSERT INTO @hashedPasswordList (HashedPassword) VALUES ('{bcrypt}$2a$10'),('{bcrypt}$2a$10$Kh8YS.'),('{bcrypt}$2a$10$safds'),('{bcrypt}$2a$10$Wl8ZKTF2YGobQ6yi')

    UPDATE accounts
    SET passwd = (select top 1 hashedPassword from @hashedPasswordList order by newid())
    WHERE email = @_email
```